# google.maps.ElevationService in Typescript cannot find LocationElevationRequest

Tags: typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, definitelytyped

In the google maps JS docs, [the example for the elevation service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation) (in short) does this:

```
var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService
elevator.getElevationForLocations({
    'locations': [location]
  }, function(results, status) {

  ... etc
})
```

but in Typescript (using `"@types/googlemaps": "3.30.19"`) I'm getting some weirdness. First, instead of the expected `google.maps.ElevationService.getElevationForLocations()` I have to use `google.maps.ElevationService.prototype.getElevationForLocations()`. Secondly, and the main issue I'm having, is that I cannot access `google.maps.LocationElevationRequest`. In the typings file I can see this:

[image: screen shot of google maps typings]

but in my code when I try `google.maps.LocationElevationRequest` I get an error `Property 'LocationElevationRequest' does not exist on type 'typeof maps'.` No amount of arbitrarily inserting `prototype` works either. Is this a hole in the typings? [This comment from a few years ago](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4364#issuecomment-105989580) claims it is accounted for.

---

*Update #1*

I am using `google.maps.PolygonOptions` in other places, which is a similar interface to `LocationElevationRequest`:

```
declare namespace google.maps {

...

  export interface PolygonOptions {
    /**
     * Indicates whether this Polygon handles mouse events. Defaults to true.
     */
    clickable?: boolean;

    ...

  }

  export interface LocationElevationRequest {
    locations: LatLng[];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol my bad. This is a Typescript noob question. Here's the proper way:

```
let request: google.maps.LocationElevationRequest = {locations: [e.latLng]}
google.maps.ElevationService.prototype.getElevationForLocations(
    request, (
        results: google.maps.ElevationResult[],
        status: google.maps.ElevationStatus) => {
            ...
        })
```